# How do I modify the session in the Django test framework

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-sessions

My site allows individuals to contribute content in the absence of being logged in by creating a User based on the current session_key

I would like to setup a test for my view, but it seems that it is not possible to modify the request.session:

I'd like to do this:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
s = Session()
s.expire_date = '2010-12-05'
s.session_key = 'my_session_key'
s.save()
self.client.session = s
response = self.client.get('/myview/')
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Thoughts on how to modify the client session before making get requests?
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252133/using-session-objects-in-django-while-testing) and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `session` is a `dict`-like object, you should use `s[x]` to get and set values

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is how I did it (inspired by a solution in http://blog.mediaonfire.com/?p=36).

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.importlib import import_module

class SessionTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10899
        settings.SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        store = engine.SessionStore()
        store.save()
        self.session = store
        self.client.cookies[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME] = store.session_key
```

After that, you may create your tests as:

```
class BlahTestCase(SessionTestCase):

    def test_blah_with_session(self):
        session = self.session
        session['operator'] = 'Jimmy'
        session.save()
```

etc...

Comment: Does this still work with django 1.6 using the Pickle serializer (instead of the now standard JSONSerializer for SESSION_SERIALIZER)

Answer (score 71):

The client object of the django testing framework makes possible to touch the session. Look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#django.test.client.Client.session for details

Be careful : `To modify the session and then save it, it must be stored in a variable first (because a new SessionStore is created every time this property is accessed)`

I think something like this below should work

```
s = self.client.session
s.update({
    "expire_date": '2010-12-05',
    "session_key": 'my_session_key',
})
s.save()
response = self.client.get('/myview/')
```

Comment: Hi Luc,  thanks for your help, but this doesn't work.  I get the following error: 

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'

This occurs because the client.session object is a dictionary.  It seems that client.session only becomes a true Session object after the request is made (and only if a user is logged in).  Any other suggestions?

You can repeat this by entering (from a shell):
from django.test import Client
client = Client()
s = client.session
s['expire_date']='2010-12-05'
s['session_key']='my_session_key'
s.save()

Comment: It looks like what luc suggested should work, but its a django bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11475

Comment: plus 1 for Andrew - this bug is at least 4 years old it seems.

Comment: Regarding the first 2 comments, I believe the bug was fixed in the [following](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21357) [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/be88b062afaa58559bb12623e8ed8843f07b97a1#diff-97160f50594424a40f2621d5a3c581ccR396).

Comment: This worked for me. Looks like the bug others commented about above is fixed.

Comment: Saving session to a variable first fixed my issue.

Answer (score 14):

As Andrew Austin already mentioned, it doesn't work because of this bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11475

What you can do though is this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SessionTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')

    def test_something_with_sessions(self):
        session = self.client.session
        session['key'] = 'value'
        session.save()
```

After creating and logging in a user with User.objects.create_user() and self.client.login(), as in the code above, sessions should work.

Answer (score 4):

as per the docs you can add values to the session in the test client via eg

```
def test_something(self):
    session = self.client.session
    session['somekey'] = 'test'
    session.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session

This will let you test views that require data in the session to function correctly.

So for this question:

```
session = self.client.session
   session['expire_date'] = '2010-12-05'
   .....
   session.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom view which inserts dummy data such as the session.

The view with the corresponding url: /dummy/:

```
def dummy(request):
    # dummy init data
    request.session['expiry_date'] = '2010-12-05'
    return HttpResponse('Dummy data has been set successfully')
```

Than in test script just call `self.client.get('/dummy/')`

I also use this dummy view to initilize the dummy data in the session when testing by hand.