# Django: How can I store session data in unit test?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-sessions

This is part of my `views.py`

**views,py**

```
.
.
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.session['from_product'] = True:
        blah blah
.
.
```

For passing this if statement, I tried to store session data in test code like this:

```
class OrderViewFromProductWithLoginTest(OrderSetupTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.login()
        self.client.session['from_product'] = True
        self.client.session.save()
```

But it doesn't work.

This is how I verified:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
session = Session.objects.first()
sessoin.get_decode()
>> {'_auth_user_backend': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 '_auth_user_hash': 'ffd87a41ff1e77abcbd78724f4b5b5133c67a08f',
 '_auth_user_id': '1'}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Look at this answer. That guy solved it pretty nice. [How do I modify the session in the Django test framework](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722483/2886270)

Comment: @AdiletMaratov This is for older versions of Django. However OP didn't mention used Django version, but I'm pretty sure it's > 1.7.

Comment: I think your problem is that you did not assign it to separate variable. See [official docs with example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session).